# Using legal descriptions of lands and their subsections to draw polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, united-states, township-range-section

I have Legal descriptions of land (Section, Township, Range) and their subsections (N1/2, S1/2, E1/2, W1/2, NW1/4, SW1/4, N1/2NW1/4, etc.)

**I want to** have a polygon encompass the subsections of the legal plots.

I intend to use county maps or a state map with already-built-in legal descriptions, so I believe there shouldn't be an issue with scale - the legal description should take me to the exact plot I want to draw over.

I'm working with a high volume of data so ideally I'll automate the drawing of the polygons.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find pre-generated PLSS (Public Land Survey System) boundaries. That is essentially what you are asking for, based on your description. It doesn't sounds like you are trying to get at irregular units of land, like with metes-and-bounds legal descriptions.

[This site](https://nationalmap.gov/small_scale/mld/plss00p.html) lets you download this dataset nationwide, I believe (it may not be available right now due to the government shutdown).